# How In LeftJoin to add additive parameter?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, left-join

In my laravel 5.7 / eloquent/ Mysql 5.5 app I need in chats listing to
get values of messsages of any chat and 1 more column of messsages of any chat for given useronly ($user_id):

I tried as :

```
$chats          = Chat
     ::select( \DB::raw( ' chats.*, count(cm.id) as messages_count, count(cmu.id) as user_messages_count' ) )
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('chats.id')
    ->leftJoin( \DB::raw('chat_messages as cm'), \DB::raw('cm.chat_id'), '=', \DB::raw('chats.id') )
    ->leftJoin( \DB::raw('chat_messages as cmu'), \DB::raw(' cmu.chat_id = chats.id and cmu.chat_id = ' .$user_id ) )
    ->get();
```

But error :

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'on clause'.
```

Looks like for leftJoin expression can not be used with empty value paramerter.
 Or in some other way?

```
$chats          = Chat
     ::select( \DB::raw( ' chats.*, count(cm.id) as messages_count, count(cmu.id) as user_messages_count' ) )
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('chats.id')
    ->leftJoin( \DB::raw('chat_messages as cm'), \DB::raw('cm.chat_id'), '=', \DB::raw('chats.id') )
    ->leftJoin(\DB::raw('chat_messages as cmu'), \DB::raw('cmu.chat_id'), '=', \DB::raw('chats.id'))
    ->where( 'cmu.user_id', $user_id)
    ->get();    // `chat_messages` ORDER BY `chat_id` A
```

That works , but not correctly as for condition

```
>where( 'cmu.user_id', $user_id)
```

left join is skipped and rows with user_messages_count = 0 are skipped, but I need them.

Which is the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know eloquent. But it's a common pitfall in Sql.  When using a LEFT JOIN, then use a criteria for the joined table in the WHERE clause then it won't return unmatched records anymore. So it becomes similar to an INNER JOIN.  In SQL a way to get around that in to put that criteria in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you seem to be missing a final single quote in :  ->leftJoin( \DB::raw('chat_messages as cmu'), \DB::raw(' cmu.chat_id = chats.id and cmu.chat_id = ' .$user_id )

Comment: Take a look at the documentation ("Advanced Join Clauses"): https://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins

Comment: Would `COUNT(CASE WHEN cmu.user_id=? THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` (with `?` being the user id) be a possible solution for your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to leftjoin more than once chat_messages.
WHERE clause is useless in this case.
LEFTJOIN works with columns in the joined tables.

```
$chats= Chat ::select( \DB::raw( ' chats.*, count(cm.id) as 
messages_count, sum(if(cm.user_id='.$user_id.',1,0)) as user_messages_count' ) )
->orderBy('name', 'asc')
->groupBy('chats.id')
->leftJoin( \DB::raw('chat_messages as cm'), \DB::raw('cm.chat_id'), '=', \DB::raw('chats.id') )
->get();    // `chat_messages` ORDER BY `chat_id` A
```